# How can I select the image link from src html part using python selenium

Tags: python, image, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all the links of the images from the below mentioned html code type:

```
<a href="#!" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-update="" data-image="https://img.xyz.com/rcmshopping/PROD_IMAGES/fffff_2018_05_10_10_49_23.jpg" data-zoom-image="https://img.xyz.com/rcmshopping/PROD_IMAGES/fffff_2018_05_10_10_49_23.jpg"> <img src="https://img.xyz.com/rcmshopping/PROD_IMAGES/fffff_2018_05_10_10_49_23.jpg"> </a>
```

I am not able to fetch any link from this part of html out f 3 any 1 is good for me. Im new to python please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the value of the *src* attribute you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='elevatezoom-gallery']/img"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.elevatezoom-gallery>img"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using the `find_elements_by_css_selector()` function.

```
links = self.webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('img[src="https://img.xyz.com/rcmshopping/PROD_IMAGES/fffff_2018_05_10_10_49_23.jpg"])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.. actually I want to extract all the image links (img.xyz.com/rcmshopping/PROD_IMAGES/fffff_2018_05_10_10_49_23.jpg) so how can I put in the link only in code

Comment: the use `self.webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('elevatezoom-gallery').get_attribute('src')`